# What is the expectation of a Brownian motion at time t given that its entire sample path exceeds H?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Suppose we have a standard Brownian motion $B(t)$ (with $B(0)=0$) and we condition on the event (which I call $R$) that:

$$B(t)\ge0 \ \forall t\in[0,K].$$

Then, how do we calculate $E(B(K)|R)$, and is it the same as $E(B(K)|B(K)\ge0)$?

Comment: $R$ has probability zero, you can't condition on it.

Comment: Fixed the mistake you pointed out.

Comment: Nope, same answer.  $R$ still has probability zero.  A Brownian motion started at zero is always (a.s.) going to begin by oscillating around zero; in particular it will always take on some strictly negative values.  This follows for example from the Blumenthal zero-one law.

Comment: @NateEldredge Actually $\mathbb P(B(0)=0)=1$ is commonly found in the definition of Brownian motion.